# Use datatable row child with a list displayed with foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with datatable plugin.

In my project, there is a table where I display a Java list (I put it in the session with Spring) with the foreach.

I am tryng to apply this plugin for my table, without success.

This is my table:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>        
            <th>Detail</th> 
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each=" view_Object : ${list}">
            <td></td>
            <td>${view_Object.name}</td>
            <td>${view_Object.surname}</td>
            <td>${view_Object.age}</td>
            <td>${view_Object.city}</td>                                                            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Every object of this list, has a list inside him (this list contains the elements that I want to show when I click on the detail button).

So, I don't need to do an Ajax call, because the detail elements are already in the object (row) shown.

But I don't know how can I do it. It's possible?

I try to use the plugin apart, to learn it, but nothing.

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63djjLbm/) taken from the [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). It doesn't work because there are no data to display. The doc use:

```
"ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt"
```

But, what should I use?

There is another way, over datatable, to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If you're creating a complete table server-side, then I think you can get it working with "Zero configuration" , i.e. $('#myTable').DataTable(); method call on client-side. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: @jyrkim, I already use zero configuration. I need the row child only..

Comment: Actually, I fiddled a bit with the hide and show table row features, but I was unsuccessful on getting the desired result. I am quite new with datatables.net aswell. Anyway good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columns.visible`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) option to hide columns containing extra details and then display that data in `format()` function.

See sample code for a table with ID `example`, adjust according to your needs.

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Age:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.age+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Start date:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.start_date+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Sallary:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.salary+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "age", "visible": false },
            { "data": "start_date", "visible": false },
            { "data": "salary", "visible": false }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abcjjdjh/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: And, If the information shown were contained into a list (I mean view_Object has a list inside him)?

Comment: @DavideFruci, enumerate that list and create additional `td` elements which you can later hide with `columns.visible` option.

Comment: @DavideFruci, I'm not familiar with syntax of your templating engine. But in my example `age`, `start_date` and `salary` are additional hidden columns that are shown in row details. I assume you need to use `each` for a list inside `view_Object` and produce a set of such columns.